# "Exactly one of HostedZoneId and HostedZoneName must be specified" in AWS::Route53::RecordSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I try to create primary failover record using AWS::Route53::RecordSet in CouldFormation:

```
  MyRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties: 
      AliasTarget: 
        DNSName: !Ref DNSName
        EvaluateTargetHealth: true
        HostedZoneId: !Ref CanonicalHostedZoneID
      Failover: PRIMARY
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      HostedZoneName: !Ref HostedZoneName
      Name: !Ref RecordName
      Type: A
```

DNSName and  CanonicalHostedZoneID are from ALB. But I get error:

"Exactly one of HostedZoneId and HostedZoneName must be specified"

Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-hostedzoneid):

> Specify either HostedZoneName or HostedZoneId, but **not both**.

In addition `SetIdentifier` is **required** for anything other than a simple record.

Please have a look at the following (only `HostedZoneId` property is set and added was `SetIdentifier`):

```
  MyRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties: 
      AliasTarget: 
        DNSName: !Ref DNSName
        EvaluateTargetHealth: true
        HostedZoneId: !Ref CanonicalHostedZoneID
      Failover: PRIMARY
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      Name: !Ref RecordName
      SetIdentifier: my-record-id
      Type: A
```